# access property and method of a class in another php file

Tags: php

I have a file with a class and some properties and methods inside the class.

I need to access the properties and methods of that class from another php file. I wanted to include the file with the class, but it is not a correct way for this situation because that file is contain some echo, which generate html and if I include that file is going to generate those html in the orher file that i dont want, I only want to access the properties and methods of the old one.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Move the functions to a third file and then include that in both.

Comment: Why dont you seperate the class into its own file?

Comment: I did not understand you. What you want to do?

Comment: it is bad approach to mix class definitions with html generation. You have faceds with problem caused by that. So why don't you separate eliminate class into single file?

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, it is a better idea to define classes in their own file with nothing but that class and include that.

someClass.php

```
<?php
class SomeClass{
    public __Construct(){
        echo "This is some class";
    }
}
```

The on other pages, you just include and instantiate the class.

```
<?php
include('someClass.php');
//do something
```

However if for some reason you can't modify the page with the class, you can use output buffering to include the page without the output.

```
<?php
//start a buffer
ob_start();
//include the page with class and html output.
include("PageWithClassAndHTMLOutput.php");
//end the buffer and discard any output
ob_end_clean();

$cls = new ClassFromIncludedPage();
$cls->someMethod();
```

This isn't ideal as you will be setting/overwriting any variables defined in the included page, parsing the entire page and doing any processing that it does. I have used this method (not for classes, but same idea) to do stuff like capture the included page and email it when it was already written to display on screen.

Answer (score 1):

So, your class has a constructor. Remove the constructor of the class and include the class file to your page. Instantiate your object and call what properties or methods you need.

```
 $object->property;
 $object->method();
```

Comment: why should constrctor be removed? why did you decide that the problem was in constructor?

Comment: It is not a problem. He says the object generates html. Therefore, I thought he instantiates the object. He could also of course use `Object::method()`

Comment: he said the "file contains echo, which generates html", not the object generates html. Sounds more like in the file with the class definition also has `echo "<blah>blah</blah>";` outside the class.

Answer (score 1):

I'll use an example from an estate web app. If for example you want to get a property name in other class than properties class (a contract class that wants to get a property name by property id) - based on Laravel 5.3 PHP framework

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers\Operations; 
## THIS CONTROLLER - that wants to access content from another (adjacent) controller

use App\Http\Controllers\Operations\PropertiesController;

      Class ContractsController extends Controller{
            public function GetContractDetails() # a local method calling a method accessing other method from another class 
            { 
                $property_id = 13;
                $data['property_name'] = (new PropertiesController)->GetPropertyName($property_id); 
                return response()->json($data, 200);
            }  
        }


<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers\Operations; 
# OTHER CONTROLLER - that is accessed by a controller in need 

Class PropertiesController extends Controller {
    Class PropertiesController extends Controller{
        public function GetPropertyName($property_id) #method called by an adjacent class
        {
            return $property_name = 'D2/101/ROOM - 201';
        } 
    }
 }
```